# Java audio Clip cannot be closed when using Linux PulseAudio

Tags: linux, audio, java, pulseaudio

I'm trying to play a sound in a Java application but the application never actually terminates because the PulseAudio Eventloop thread is left running even after trying to [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#close--) the [`Clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) instance used for playing the sound:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

final class AudioClipTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        try (AudioInputStream instream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/test-sound.wav"))){
            final AudioFormat format = instream.getFormat();
            final Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format));
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                @Override
                public void update(final LineEvent event) {
                    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        System.out.println("Finished playing audio.");
                        event.getLine().close();
                        // FIXME: This line is never reached on Linux with
                        // PulseAudio
                        System.out.println("Closed audio data line.");
                    }
                }
            });
            clip.open(instream);
            clip.start();
        }
    }

}
```

On my Linux machine<sup>†</sup>, the above main method plays the relevant sound, prints

> Finished playing audio.

and then hangs, while on a Windows<sup>‡</sup> machine it prints

> Finished playing audio.
>
> Closed audio data line.

and exits properly.

The actual `Clip` implementation used on the Linux machine is `org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip` whereas on Windows it is `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.DirectClip`; **What is going on here? — What is `PulseAudioClip.close()` doing which isn't returning?**

---

<sup>†</sup>**Distribution:** *Linux Mint 18.1*; **Kernel:** *4.4.0-92-generic x86_64*; **OpenJDK:** *8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3*; **PulseAudio:** *1:8.0-ubuntu3.3*

<sup>‡</sup>**Distribution:** *Windows 10 Pro*; **Version:** *1703*; **OS Build:** *15063.540 x64*; **Oracle JDK:** *1.8.0_144-b01*; **DirectX:** *version 12*

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to work around this issue is to use the Alsa (userspace) API for playing audio using Java. The alsa userspace API will redirect to PulseAudio (or another API/mixer) so you should still get correct audio.

Edit `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/sound.properties` and comment out everything related to `org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio` and add this:

```
javax.sound.sampled.Clip=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
javax.sound.sampled.Port=com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider
javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
```

Also, please file a bug against your distribution's openjdk package. The PulseAudio/Java bindings have been unsupported for years now and should be removed.