# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:No Line Interface matching Clip supporting format

Tags: java, audio

Im writing a video game with music and sfx. On 3/4 machines I have tested this on, everything has run smoothly. On the other machine, loading any sort of sound file produces this exception: [image: IllegalArgumentException]
I only did a stack trace for the music tracks, but this error occurs for all sounds used by the game (as you can see in the terminal with the "buzz" sound effect). The `NullPointerException` is only thrown because the sound was not properly loaded. Here is the code that causes the `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
    try{
        c=AudioSystem.getClip();
        c.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Resources/Songs/"+name+".wav")));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Song name not recognized: "+name);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ignore the "Song name not recognized" bit, that's usually invoked by a `FileNotFoundException` and simply is helpful if I've made a typo somewhere else.
Here's what I do know: 
 1. this glitch can't be related to the length of the sound, as its failing both for the 5 minute songs and the 1 second sfx.
 2. this glitch may be caused by the system unable to open a clip because of `AudioSystem.getClip()` failing on systems with certain specs. (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7026275)

How do I prevent this from happening regardless of the systems specs? Or is this caused by something else entirely?
The machine on which this occurred is a friend of mine's and as such I do not have immediate access to her computer.

Comment: Include error messages *as text*.

Comment: Normally I would have, but as I said this happened on a friends computer and she sent me a screenshot of it

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194666/java-audio-fails-to-play-wav-file-in-linux/46324854#46324854). It may help.

Comment: The nullpointer exception isnt the problem. It's just a result of the audio file not being buffered into the code. The problem is within the code I posted. It gives a null pointer because later the game calls for the music to be played, and where it normally can expect the `Clip` to be loaded, it is not.

Comment: Something is wrong here.  You should not be calling `gameTick` from a paintComponent method.  You have no control over how often paintComponent is called—the underlying system may call it several times for a single exposure event, or may call it in response to the mouse moving over the component.

Comment: That doesn't even relate to the audio problem. Also, paintComponent calls itself with repaint(), and gameTick is interpolated based on the system time in nanos, so that isnt even a problem generally speaking, that's just how the engine works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by having the person update their sound drivers.